# Updating a column in a very large SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a task on my dev databases to update some customer PII.  Some of these tables have many rows and are quite large (on the order of 51 million+ and 25GB in size). Every row in the table will need to be updated so right now I'm just running a simple update statement without a where clause on a single column, and this query is, at the time of this post, running 35mins+.  Is there a faster way to update large tables? or a better way to mask PII data?

Current query is just

```
update mytable
set mycolumn = 'some text'
```

Comment: Do it in batches. Perhaps 100 000 rows per UPDATE.

Comment: Tips for large table updates will vary depending on how you [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) the question